# How to retrieve array wise data of a specific column for an id in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I want to retrieve array wise data from a specific column of a specific id.

Suppose I have a table named `product_wise_ingredients_tbl`.

```
product_id   ingredient_id   quantity
----------   -------------   --------
  1               1           100
  1               3           50
  1               4           20
  2               1           80
  2               2           70
```

here is the `product_tbl`

```
  id   name   price
----- ------ -------
  1     1      100
  1     3      50
  1     4      20
  2     1      80
```

Here is the `ingredient_tbl`

```
  id   name   qty
----- ------ -------
  1     1      100
  1     3      200
  1     4      200
  2     1      800
```

Now I want to retrieve `product_id` wise array data from `product_wise_ingredients_tbl` like below format

```
[1] => Array
            (
                [ingredient_id] => Array
                (
                    [0]=>1
                    [1]=>3
                    [2]=>4
                ),
                [quantity] => Array
                (
                    [0]=>100
                    [1]=>50
                    [2]=>20
                )                
            )

[2] => Array
            (
                [ingredient_id] => Array
                (
                    [0]=>1
                    [1]=>2
                ),
                [quantity] => Array
                (
                    [0]=>80
                    [1]=>70
                )                
            )
```

I have already tried but that was not the perfect query.

```
$data = DB::table('product_wise_ingredient_measurements')
            ->join('products', 'products.id', '=', 'product_wise_ingredient_measurements.products_id')
            ->join('ingredients', 'ingredients.id', '=', 'product_wise_ingredient_measurements.ingredients_id')
            ->select('product_wise_ingredient_measurements.*', 'products.product_name as products_name', 'ingredients.name as ingredients_name')
            ->where('product_wise_ingredient_measurements.products_id','=',$pro_wise_ingre_measurement->products_id)
            ->get();
```

How can I do that? Anybody Help Please? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using relationship ?

Comment: Can you pls share the products and ingredients table schema

Comment: @ManojKiranAppathurai...I have updated my question. Please have a look

Comment: @ManojKiranAppathurai....still not.... will you please help with that?

Comment: You can use many-to-many relationship here. For example, A product has many ingredients and An Ingredient is present in many products.  Once you define the relationships, you can write something like `$product->ingredients()` and `$ingredient->products()`. Refer: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many .